# Generate script for schema and data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a SQL Server database. In SQL Server Management Studio I generate a script of data and schema (Tasks -> Generate Scripts ->.. etc).

Can I generate this script (Schema and data) in SQLCmd?

Before, I used BackUp and Restore for cloning DBs, but now I don't have permissions to restore databases on the server, and I need to use a script.

```
--- My code for .bat ---
:: BackUp and restore DB
:: Create BackUp Prod DB
SqlCmd -U <user> -P <pass> -S <ip_MSSQL> -Q "USE <MyDb> EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='<network_drive>', @databaseName='MyDb', @backupType='F'"
:: Copy BackUps from temp folder to D:\BD\
set lpath=<network_drive>\MyDB_FULL_
set rpath=*.BAK
copy %lpath%%rpath% D:\BD\

:: Update/Restore Dev DB from Prod BackUp
SqlCmd -U <user> -P <pass> -S <ip_MSSQL> -Q "DECLARE @Data varchar(100) SET @Data = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),101),'/','') DECLARE @BackupFile varchar(100) SET @BackupFile=N'D:\BD\MyDB_FULL_' + @Data + N'.BAK' RESTORE DATABASE DevMyDb FROM DISK=@BackupFile with move 'MyDB' to 'D:\DB\DevMyDB.mdf', move 'MyDB_log' to 'D:\DB\DevMyDB_log.ldf'"
:: Delete BackUp in temp folder
del <network_drive>\MyDB_FULL_*.BAK /s /q
```

P.S. For backup I use a stored procedure - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698

Comment: take a look at Database Compare in SSDT. It can generate script for both schema and data.

Comment: Hi, I've made some minor edits to your question to improve readability and to remove the tag from title (it's not necessary to be there since it's in the tags, which show up in the questions list). If you dislike the changes, you're able to roll them back from the [revisions page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39873019/revisions).

Comment: SquirrelSql can generated data insert scripts from your tables. Not sure what you mean by having SQLCmd doing that for you, as that is the new ISQL - a command line tool for executing the queries.

Comment: I mean, I wanted to write a script for autogeneration sql file, and start automatically on the selected database (to clone the schema and data).

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot generate scripts with SqlCmd.  However, you can generate them with Powershell. Also, there are a number of free utilities of varying quality that can generate SQL scripts.

Comment: You should note that Backup is almost always faster.

Comment: **RBarryYoung** Thanks, I'm still hoping use stored procedure. I'll try Powershell.